# Values of image pixels according to the colorbar

Tags: matplotlib

Let a four-pixel image is as follows

```
image = array([[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]],
               [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]], dtype=float32)
```

that is, all four pixels are blue and in the colour scale bar their values are zero. I want to estimate the sum of all pixel values of an image according to the scale bar. For example, for the above case the sum of all pixel values is `0.0`. I tried earlier with `image.sum()`, but this gives `4.0` and this is not the result I need. Any help please?

Comment: Don't do the RGB mapping your self, let mpl do that for you.

Comment: Why do you expect the sum to be zero?

Comment: @askewchan: As we discussed earlier that is the total brightness of my astronomical object at this four pixel, that means there is no brighter object in these four cells. I said you that I was getting wrong result with image.sum().sum() and I figured it out as the reason.

Comment: Oh, hello @user3503692, I didn't realize it was you :)

Comment: Does this give the value you expected?  `np.asarray(Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8')*255).convert('L')).astype(float)/255`

Comment: Image.fromarray is not working for the data given above. I get an attribute error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fromarray'

Comment: `from PIL import Image`. Note that `Image` is not `image`.