# Relationship for convert the rgb touple to a real number

Tags: matplotlib

Is there any relationship to convert a [r,g,b] tuple to a real number x, which is mapped on the the colorscale 0 to 1. Something like x = b + n*g + n^2*r. For example, this relationship will give [1,0,0] -> 1 and [0,0,1] -> 0.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 8 bits each for r, g, and b, one simple mapping is `(r + 2^8 * g + 2^16 * b) / 2^24`.  The [r,g,b] triple is just a 24-bit value, so this reduces it to the range (0, 1).

Comment: Thanks Paul for your reply. Your given relationship gives [1.0, 0.0, 0.0](red) -> 1 and [0.0,0.0, 0.0](black) -> 0. I am looking for something like red->1 and blue ->1, Or, if you let me know the colorscheme it will be produced by the given relationship that also work. Would you please give me any reference where can I read about the rgb mapping relationships.

Comment: This simple mapping doesn't describe any standard color scheme, but is just a direct conversion of a standard 24-bit color value [r,g,b] into a float between 0 and 1.  Red [1,0,0] maps to 1/2^24 in this case, while blue [0,0,1] maps to 1/2^8.  Are you looking for both of these to map to the same value (1)?  In any case, maybe this will help: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV).  With RGB-->YUV conversion, the Y value provides an intensity measure independent of the color, so maybe this is more along the lines of what you want.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake, red->1, and blue->0

Comment: If you are trying to compute brightness, as you mentioned, then RGB --> YUV is the way to go.  The Y component gives you precisely that (i.e., intensity), while the U and V components contain only color information.  The RGB --> YUV conversion is a simple matrix multiplication, as described at the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I read about RGB-> YUV. The problem with Y is that it weights green more than red which will misinterpret my brightness image. For example, Y of red[1.,0.,0.] is less than Y of yellow[1., 1., 0.]. However on the brightness (of the astronomical object) scale red>yellow. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes, YUV is geared towards human perception.  Another option might be RGB --> HSV and take the V component, which indicates brightness: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space).  I thought in astronomy, you'd have red-yellow-white-blue in order of brightness.

Answer (score 2):

The tuple RGB is a three-dimensional quantity with granularity specific to the domain you're applying it to, so yes and no.  You would need to contain the data of a cubic space in the space of a line, so if you compacted a 3D vector into a scalar, assuming the scalar has the same granularity of each individual dimension of the vector, you would necessarily be losing data.  However, if you're okay with that, or if the granularity of the vector components and the scalar are different (scalar being at least the cubic granularity of the components), or infinite, you can.

Comment: Hi GameKyuubi, I do not understand the granularity. Is it something like the pixel size? I have a 2D image with 700x28 pixel and I want to replace the rgb colour tuple associated with each pixel to its corresponding real number (according to a relationship which actually produce the colour scale, say max(red)=1 and min(blue)= 0). Do you think this transformation will not a good one?

Comment: By granularity I mean precision.  For example, you can't contain the vector [r,g,b] where each component is a float, in a single float c, without losing precision.  For a simple example, if we assume that r, g, and b, each contain 2 states, 0 and 1, to represent each state of the vector we'd need 8 states, or 2^3 states.

Comment: The precision of your real number X must necessarily have the precision of your vector components cubed.  This is fine if you have infinite precision, but in practical application you need to think about the space your numbers take up.

Comment: Thank you GameKyuubi for your time. So without losing data it is impossible to get a unique colorscale value for each pixel. My actual problem was to estimate the values of each pixels colorvalue (according to the colorscale bar) and sum them for the whole image. I issued another question about that (please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907233/values-of-image-pixels-according-to-the-colorbar) Do you suggest me a way to do that.

Comment: Yes. Exactly, brightness of an astronomical object.

Comment: Absolute brightness or relative brightness?  In your other question it seems like you are trying to get relative brightness and not absolute brightness, which are two different things and the reason you're getting 4 instead of 0.